# How do I prevent a ScrollViewer in WPF from eating the scroll event if the Scrollbar is auto hidden

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ScrollViewer that contains everything in this window and some ItemControls that dynamically grow and shrink depending om how many items they contain. I have wrapped them in ScrollViewers and capped their height to 400 so that the ScrollViewers become scrollable once they become taller than 400 pixels. The ScrollViewers also contain some other stuff like a textbox and button to create a new item to add to the ItemsControl that I only want to bring into view once the users has scrolled all the way to the bottom.

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Margin="20">
        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl>
                ...                                
            </ItemsControl>  
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl>
                ...                                
            </ItemsControl> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                ...
            </StackPanel>       
        </ScrollViewer>                    
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now for my problem: when the ItemControls are smaller then 400 pixels, the scrollbar auto hides as it should but it still eats the mousewheel events. What I would like is that it just scrolls the outer ScrollViewer instead.

I know I can change the properties of the ScrollViewer when it auto hides like this but there doesn't seem to be a property to stop it from trying to scroll anyway even though there is nothing to scroll.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Collapsed">
                What do I put here?
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The only things that seem to work are `IsEnabled="False"` but that also disables everything inside the ScrollViewer which I do not want and `IsHittestVisible="False"` which has the same problem of not letting me interact with anything inside the ItemsControl which I need.

I have also tried some stuff with the `PreviewMouseEvent` but nothing I tried seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any clean solution with only the XAML but you can reroute the event in the code behind.

Set the **VerticalScrollBarVisibility** of the children on **Auto**

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" x:Key="ScrollviewerChildren">
                <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="250"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
```

Then add the same event to both of the "Children". (You can do that in the XAML or the code behind)

```
        sc1.PreviewMouseWheel += Sc_PreviewMouseWheel;
        sc2.PreviewMouseWheel += Sc_PreviewMouseWheel;
```

Finally, if the **ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility** is "**Collapsed**", call the **ScrollToVerticalOffset** of the main scrollviewer with the Delta value (Substract it from the actual VerticalOffset)

```
    private void Sc_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (s.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
        //Scroll to the actual position - the delta scrolled
            ParentScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ParentScroll.VerticalOffset-e.Delta);
        }
    }
```

However, I'm not that happy because calling the ScrollToVerticalOffset method like that produces another scrolling behaviour than the usual stuff: The scrolling distance is not the same. You can try to adapt/improve this according to your needs. But I'm sure there's a cleaner solution, I just haven't found it for the moment

About the ScrollToVerticalOffset & VerticalOffset:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for helping, this almost works, but it seems to set the parent ScrollViewer to the value Delta, rather than scrolling it down by an amount equal to delta. In other words: it first jumps back all the way to the top, and then scrolls a little.

Comment: Of course, I made a mistake. ScrollToVerticalOffset(double o) scroll to an absolute position, not to a relative one. I'll edit he answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: I was able to figure it out on my own, changing to argument to `ParentScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta` makes it work

Comment: I just made the edit just now :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on tstx's answer I was able to make it work, generalizing it a bit to make it easier to reuse.

I put a style in the resources of the outer scrollviewer so that I don't have subscribe to the PreviewMouseWheel event for each child ScrollViewer individually.

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseWheel" Handler="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"/>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And in the code-behind I made it search for the parent scrollviewer so that the function can be reused:

```cs
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (s.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
        var ParentScrollViewer = FindParentScrollViewer(s);
        if (ParentScrollViewer is null) return;
        ParentScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ParentScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    }
}

private ScrollViewer FindParentScrollViewer(DependencyObject child)
{
    //get parent item
    DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    //end of visual tree, no ScrollViewer Found
    if (parentObject is null) return null;
    //check if the parent is scrollviewer and return if so
    return parentObject is ScrollViewer parent ? parent : FindParentScrollViewer(parentObject);
}
```

I tried putting it all in a behavior and applying it to all ScrollViewers so that it just works everywhere but I couldn't figure out how to apply a behavior to all Controlls of a certain type because they cannot be set using styles so this is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to override the WPF `ScrollViewer` with my own `ScrollViewer` that behaves properly.

It is actually quite small, here is the complete source code together with `using` directives and comments:

```cs
namespace MyWpf.Controls;

using System.Windows.Input;
using Wpf = System.Windows;
using WpfControls = System.Windows.Controls;

// PEARL: The WPF ScrollViewer eats all MouseWheel events even if its vertical scrollbar is not visible.
//        We correct this problem with this derived ScrollViewer which does not behave like that.
//        See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76458221/773113
public class MyScrollViewer : WpfControls.ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel( MouseWheelEventArgs e )
    {
        if( ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Wpf.Visibility.Collapsed )
            return;
        base.OnMouseWheel( e );
    }
}
```